# phrase or idiom meaning 'I don't have enough money nowadays.'

Tags: phrases, synonyms, slang, colloquialisms

Is there any phrase or idiom meaning 'I don't have enough money nowadays'?

I just want to know sentences which are used in everyday life.

Comment: "Things are pretty tight."

Comment: "I'm barely making ends meet."

Comment: "Why is there so much month left at the end of the money?"

Comment: My finances are on the rocks just now. I am going to run out of money. We will run dry with money.  Are you short of funds?

Answer (score 4):

"I don't have enough money nowadays" sounds odd. I would say, "I have been lacking in funds lately." You might be asking for slang, which changes over time and differs from place to place.

As an American growing up in the 1950s, I use the expressions:

- I'm broke.
- I'm short of cash.

Since people generally do not like to admit they are broke, they usually minimize the problem, saying, for instance, "I can't afford x", where x is the direct object. E.g.,

- I can't afford a new car.
- I can't afford lunch today.

There are also many idioms for being broke, such as,

- I am poor as a church mouse
- I am living from pillar to post
- The wolf is at my door.

  There is also the vulgar expression,
- "I don't have a pot to piss in."

Answer (score 1):

"I'm broke" is the most basic.

Alternatively "I'm skint".

Comment: I never heard the expression "skint". I wonder when and where that expression is from.

Comment: @RobertMenuet - I've never heard "skint", but I've read it a handful of times.  No recollection of where, though.

Comment: it's a variant of 'skinned' in the sense of 'stripped of the skin', which is actually a bit barbaric in the context of money

Comment: @Steven - This might be a good answer to the question, but (as you can see) it could be improved with some supporting references, definitions or examples.

Comment: "skint" may be Australia specific.  The Australian Oxford gives this definition ..  "having no money left, origin=skinned"